# Add Org or peer in Org dynamically in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am using http://hyperledger-fabric-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html for Hyperledger Fabric setup in Ubuntu VM. As per tutorial (fabric-samples/first-network) which have two organizations with two peers have been created. I wanted to add new organization or new peer in already existing Organization dynamically. Kindly help me know the steps to add dynamically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't to the point of being "dynamic" just yet. However, the reconfiguration is done using the `configtxlator` tool to read the genesis block and modify it's contents, then submit it as a new transaction that updates the network/channel configuration. Please see the tutorial on `configtxlator` [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/master/configtxlator.html).

Answer (score 2):

New version i.e the testing version of hrperledger fabric v1.1-preview gives this feature of adding new org dynamically. Main role in this is of configtxlator, jq and configtxgen. They have given fabric-samples/first-network new example which fo this work. Download the pdf of hyperledger fabric and go to chaper 11 i.e page 59 https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/hyperledger-fabric/latest/hyperledger-fabric.pdf you will get good documentation of how it is done. Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

[IBM has a step-by-step guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-add-an-organization-to-your-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/index.html) showing in details how to use `configxlator`, as adding a new Org section in config JSON is not so trivial and there are additional steps, such as signing the update config block.